# Can I do an external splice to my chandelier wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

My ceilings are over 20 feet tall so I want to avoid renting scaffolding to replace the chandelier at the junction box.

Comment: Could you explain “splice” I am not sure if you are adding a new light or want to power a new light from this light.

Comment: Actually to replace an existing lighting fixture.  Because the ceilings are so high (20 feet), I am wondering if the electrician could cut the existing hanging light fixture and splice in the new fixture (reusing the existing wire & chain).

Comment: Probably. This would be a question for the electrician...more than anyone here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok like with a swagger lamp. It might be possible. A swagger lamp has a connection inside the globe. Some chandeliers have a wiring space where a junction can be made. All junctions need to be in a box or inside the fixture So it may be possible to do it legally by cutting the line and chain it may end up slightly higher depending on the style but now that I understand what you are asking it could be done with the right new fixture.

Comment: so a splice in the wire is not code compliant?

Comment: Exposed splices are not code compliant, no.  All splices need to be made inside a junction box or fixture.  In this case, what Ed Beal is suggesting is to simply clip your current wire as close to the fixture as possible, and make the splice inside the body of the new fixture.  You may need to mount the new fixture a few inches higher to get enough length of wire inside of it, but that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: So even though the wire is exposed down the chain, you couldn't have two straight, insulated,crimp splices in that cable and then thread it through additional chain?  (I never did this, always replaced the wire)